# I am not Getting where can i do correlation using Jmeter in my application. I ma new to Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

Our application login is related to Google authentication. While i am recording script using Blaze meter it is working fine. I ma importing same file into the Jmeter. If i am doing the execution using this script it is getting fail. I came to know the we need to correlate the Barer token. I am new to Jmeter and i am not sure where it is generating Token.

[Image for sample script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKMZr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One screenshot is not enough to help you, you'd better ask your network administrator and/or application developers which auth protocol of [Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity) is being used under the hood, what is the authorization flow and how the token can be obtained.

As long as you don't need to test the identity platform itself it should be possible to assign a static non-expiring token for the user which you can add to your tests via the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and that would be it.

In case if it's not possible you will have to go the "hard" way, reference material can be found:

- [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter)
- [How to Load Test OpenId Secured Websites](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-load-test-openid-secured-websites)